# Dibujar Polígono de Google Maps

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

Tengo todas las coordenadas de mi polígono almacenadas en mi base de datos. Desde [php](/questions/tagged/php) creo un array de *JSON* con estas coordenadas y las retorno al [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) que hace el llamado a la función que se encargar de dibujar mi poligono. Cuando le doy los datos quemados en el código [html](/questions/tagged/html) funciona perfecto, pero al momento de hacerlo como se los explico me sale un error en consola que dice:

> `message: "not an Array"`

Ya intenté retornar desde [php](/questions/tagged/php) un array y nada, tambien desde [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) convertirlo array y tampoco. Les dejo mi código para dar una idea.

> **PHP:**

```
<?php
include '../../funcionalidad/zonasFuncion.php';

$obj = new zonasFuncion($_POST);
$zonasDefault = $obj->coordenadasZonaDefault();
if(count($zonasDefault)<1){
    echo '0|Error';
    exit;
}else{  
    $dataZona = "[";
        foreach ($zonasDefault as $zonaDefault) {
            $dataZona .= '{lat: '.$zonaDefault['zonCor_latitud'].' , lng: '.$zonaDefault['zonCor_longitud'].'},';           
        }
    $dataZona = trim($dataZona, ',')."]";   

    echo $dataZona;
    exit();
}
?>
```

> **Ajax:**

```
$.ajax({
                data: parametros,
                url: '../mediador/zonas/consultarCoordenadasZonaCentro.php',                            
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
               success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    dibujarZona(result);                    
                },
                error : function(xhr, status) {
                    console.log('Disculpe, existió un problema en estadisticas de recaudo por mes conductor');
                },
                // código a ejecutar sin importar si la petición falló o no
                complete : function(xhr, status) {
                    //console.log('Petición ajax realizada');
                }
        });
```

> **Javascript:**

```
function dibujarZona(coordenadas){        
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapa'), {
          zoom: 14,
          center: {lat: 4.656225, lng: -74.052000},          
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
        var triangleCoords = coordenadas;

        // Construct the polygon.
        var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: triangleCoords,
          strokeColor: 'RGB(2,136,209)',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 1,
          fillColor: 'RGB(2,136,209)',
          fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
        bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);   
    }
```

---

*Estructura del array "coordenadas":*

> ```
> [
> {lat: ###### , lng: ######},
> {lat: ###### , lng: ######},
> {lat: ###### , lng: ######},
> {lat: ###### , lng: ######},
> {lat: ###### , lng: ######}
> ]
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solucion que encontre fue la siguiente:

PHP:

```
$dataZona = array();
        foreach ($zonasDefault as $zonaDefault) 
        {
            $zonaDefault['lat']=(double)$zonaDefault['lat'];
            $zonaDefault['lng']=(double)$zonaDefault['lng'];
            $dataZona[] = $zonaDefault;         
        }
    echo json_encode($dataZona);
    exit();
```

AJAX:

```
success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    var array = JSON.parse(result);                    
                    dibujarZona(array);                    
                },
```

y listo ya dibuja sobre el mapa el polígono. Saludos !!

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es muy sencillo, `coordenadas` es un `string`, no un `array` que es lo que espera la librería JS de Google, por eso mismo te dice que no es un array (`message: "not an Array"`)

Añade un `eval` para que JavaScript interprete dicha `string` como un `array` y ya te debería de funcionar.

```
var triangleCoords = eval(coordenadas);
```

Otra opcion sería decirle al objeto Ajax de jQuery que el resultado que devuelve el php es un JSON con la opción `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: Hola NetVicious, si tienes razon cuando seguí indagando y encontré que lo que tenia era un string, corregi mi codigo php y poco el ajax dejare la solución a continuación, Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Ok, la parte que has tocado en el PHP saca lo mismo, sólo que lo generas de una forma más cómoda. Y la parte del succes del ajax es convertir el string a JSON que es más o menos lo mismo que hace el eval que puse yo. Me alegro que encontrases la solución.